# Two GUI Wallets: One Daemon?

Tags: daemon

I have two GUI wallets (or accounts to be more accurate) on my Windows PC. I can be up to date with the daemon in one, but when I open the other account, the daemon is far behind. Is this normal behavior or is it there an issue here that can be corrected? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean it never catches up ? If you want someone to answer your question, you need to be clear about what's happening.

Comment: It's possible that one of the wallets isn't synced with the daemon yet. It can take a while if the wallet is old and has't been synced for a while. Can you give us some more information please. Did you create the two wallets at the same time? Did you create both of them with the GUI or are they old? What does the progress bar in the GUI show?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the issue was solved. Perhaps I had two copies of the daemon and the two different wallets were using the different daemons. In any case. All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is contradicting itself. The same **daemon cannot be up-to-date and far behind at the same time**. It is either one or the other for both wallets. What is most likely, as Jaquee hinted at, is that one of the wallet synchronizations is far behind (thus not the daemon). When connected, you should give it time to catch-up.

It is definitely possible to open multiple wallets using the same daemon (one after another with the GUI, or simultaneously with the CLI).